# Can I compose ReadS and ReadP?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to compose a parser with `ReadP`, and I wanted to use `read` to parse numbers. But I must be missing something because even the most trivial example misbehaves:

```
λ import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP
λ (readP_to_S . readS_to_P $ (read :: ReadS Int)) "123" :: [(Int, String)]
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

I even specified the types everywhere, but it just does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to replace your use of `read` with `reads`:

```
> (readP_to_S . readS_to_P $ (reads :: ReadS Int)) "123" :: [(Int, String)]
                              ^^^^^
[(123,"")]
```

It's unfortunate that it typechecked with `read`, but it's because the type signature for `read` is so general.  In fact, the parser `read :: ReadS Int` is trying to parse a list of tuples of integers and strings!!!

```
> (read :: ReadS Int) "[(1,\"hi\"),(2,\"bye\")]"
[(1,"hi"),(2,"bye")]
```

which is definitely not what you want.